# wordpress post link error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just upgraded to wordpress version 3.5 and using guesthouse theme. It used to work fine with wp previous version. However, after upgrading. I got this error whatever click on post link .

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function options() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\guesthouse\ait-cache\_Nette.FileTemplate\_Templates.main-single-ait-room.php-16702044d886e338830f0567f9043065.php on line 74
```

Anybody has any idea what's wrong with that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you updatethe GuestHouse theme to the latest version? It might have compatibility issue with WP3.5

http://themeforest.net/item/guesthouse-hotel-sport-center-2in1-premium-theme/1453399